# Converting binary to string from one location to other

Tags: c++, c, byte, converters

I am trying to convert data from binary form to string resource,
so far I got this code but it isn't working right any suggetions?
The code is in c/c++

```
char* binaryToString(char* b) {
    int length = strlen(b);
    char* result = (char*)malloc(length / 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++, b += 8) {
        result[i] = strtol(b, NULL, 2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please explain the idea behind every line of code. What is the input? What is the actual output? What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++? They are not the same language and the answers may be different.

Answer (score 1):

you allocate an array of `length/8` elements but you write at the indexes 0 up to `length - 1` => you write out of the allocated array, the behavior is undefined

replace

```
char* result = (char*)malloc(length / 8);
```

by

```
char* result = malloc(length);
```

or of course change your loop

Currently you will also very probably read out of the array managed by *b* because you progress of 8 char each time, so you call *strtol* from index  0, then 8 ... then `8*(length-1)`, reading out of an array as an undefined behavior

Other problems

- you assign your array of `char`with `long`, do you really want to do that ?
- *strtol* will certainly not produce the values your expect progressing as you do in the input string

---

From your remarks one way to do is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* binaryToString(char * b)
{
  size_t n = (strlen(b) + 7) / 8;
  char * result = malloc(n + 1);
  size_t i;
  
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++, b += 8) {
    char s[9];
    
    strncpy(s, b, 8);
    s[8] = 0;
    result[i] = (char) strtol(s, NULL, 2);
  }
  result[i] = 0;
  
  return result;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  while (--argc) {
    argv += 1;
    
    char * r = binaryToString(*argv);
    
    printf("%s -> %s\n", *argv, r);
    free(r);
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

I use a buffer to copy each block of up to 8 character to not modify the input string.

Warnings :

- that supposes a char can support a value from 0 up to 255 (see `CHAR_BIT`)
- the validity of the input string is not check even *strtol* allows to do that.
- if the length of the input string is not a multiple of 8 but is greater than 8 the result is not the expected one even there is no undefined behavior.
- the result can contains non readable characters including null character(s) before the null character put in the last position of the allocated array.

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall -g cv.c 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 01100001011100110110010001100110 100001 0110000100000000011100110110010001100110
01100001011100110110010001100110 -> asdf
100001 -> !
0110000100000000011100110110010001100110 -> a
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out 01100001011100110110010001100110 100001 0110000100000000011100110110010001100110
==12327== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12327== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12327== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12327== Command: ./a.out 01100001011100110110010001100110 100001 0110000100000000011100110110010001100110
==12327== 
01100001011100110110010001100110 -> asdf
100001 -> !
0110000100000000011100110110010001100110 -> a
==12327== 
==12327== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12327==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12327==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 1,037 bytes allocated
==12327== 
==12327== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12327== 
==12327== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==12327== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

(in the case of 0110000100000000011100110110010001100110 the second character of the result is the null char so the next characters are not printed)

Comment: if it gets 01010101 its strlen will be 8? and i need 1

Comment: result needs to be length of future string which will need to be 8 times smaller than binary 'string'

Comment: @NikolaNikolic the indexes must be between 0 and the number of elements minus one

Comment: @NikolaNikolic what is your goal ? to get a string representing a binary number and to produce an array corresponding to the same number in base 256 ?

Comment: if i change just the line for length  int length = strlen(b) / 8; it solves the problem? i also changed the line with malloc

Comment: i need to make a function that gets string with zeros and ones and make a string that is ASCII formated

Comment: every eight numbers from original string b i cast with strtol and put it in string result

Comment: the *strtol* is not doing what you suppose because it works on all the string from b then b+8 etc

Comment: @NikolaNikolic you do not answer to my question , what is the goal ? `make a string that is ASCII formated` ascii formating of what value ? Edit your question to give an example of input and the output you expect

Comment: 01100001011100110110010001100110 => "asdf" this is what i need input of binary and string result

Comment: @NikolaNikolic there is no guaranty the result if redable, I mean to get the ascii code of non control characters. input 0000000100000002 will produce characters code 1 and 2. As I said earlier you want  number in base 256

Comment: as i am the one putting the string in binary form i know it will be legit ascii values so i just need to make a funciton that will give me  01100001011100110110010001100110 => "asdf"

Comment: @NikolaNikolic I edited my answer to add a proposal

Comment: why the +7 on size_t n?

Comment: @NikolaNikolic to manage the case the length is not a multiple of 8 in the right way. Of course 7 is `8-1`

Answer (score 1):

`strtol` interpret the input string as one whole number, because you do not have blank spaces between each every 8-char group. So, I propose a simple fix for you, copying each group of characters into a buffer, and append a '\0' at the end of the buffer.

Also, I fixed the length calculation error.

```
char* binaryToString(char* b) {
    int length = (strlen(b)+7)/8 + 1;
    char buf[9];
    buf[8] = '\0';
    char* result = (char*)malloc(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++, b += 8) {
        strncpy(buf, b, 8);
        result[i] = strtol(buf, NULL, 2);
    }
    result[length - 1] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

Comment: why do you add +1 on length? I think the code will run fine just remove that +1 and change the null to go to result[length]

Answer (score 0):

[`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) will consume as many characters as possible to convert to an integer value. It doesn't know you only want to convert the next 8 binary digits. Instead of trying to work around that behavior, you might do the conversion yourself. For example:

```
char *binaryToString(const char *b)
{
    int length = strlen(b) / 8;
    char *result = malloc(length + 1);
    if (result) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            // convert 8 binary digits to integer value
            int value = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
                value = (value << 1) + *b++ - '0';
            }
            result[i] = value;
        }
        result[length] = '\0'; // string must be null terminated
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note this doesn't do the error checking that `strtol` does.